# Reproducing the dot product function in a for loop in GLSL does not output wanted results

Tags: glsl

In the code below you will find, within the for loop with 10 iterations, a commented out line that involves calculating a dot product by using the GLSL dot() function.

Below the commented line I am trying to reproduce the dot product(please look in the code), but the ongoing results are black screen.

```c
    #ifdef GL_ES
    precision mediump float;
    #endif
    
    uniform float time;
    uniform vec2 mouse;
    uniform vec2 resolution;
    
    void main()
    {   
        float time_ = (time+10.) * 30.0;
        vec2 uv = (-resolution.xy + 2.0 * gl_FragCoord.xy ) / resolution;
        float s = 0.0;
        float v = -0.010;
        float t = time_*0.005;
        uv.x += sin(t) * 0.15;
        vec3 color = vec3(0.0);
        vec3 init = vec3(-0.25, -0.25 + sin(time_ * 0.001) * 0.4, floor(time_) * 0.0008);
        for (int r = 0; r < 100; r++) 
        {
            vec3 p = init + s * vec3(uv, 0.143);
            p.z = mod(-p.z, 2.0)-1.0;
            for (int i=0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                //p = abs(p * 2.003) / dot(p, p) - 0.75;
                p.x = abs(p.x * 2.003) / (p.x*p.x+p.y*p.y+p.z*p.z) - 0.75;
                p.y = abs(p.y * 2.003) / (p.x*p.x+p.y*p.y+p.z*p.z) - 0.75;
                p.z = abs(p.z * 2.003) / (p.x*p.x+p.y*p.y+p.z*p.z) - 0.75;
            }
            //v += length(p * p) * smoothstep(0.0, 0.1, 0.9 - s) * .0005;
            v += sqrt((p.x*p.x*p.x*p.x)+(p.y*p.y*p.y*p.y)+(p.z*p.z*p.z*p.z)) * smoothstep(0.0, 0.1, 0.9 - s) * .0005;
    
            color+=vec3(v*0.02);
            s += .005;
        }
        gl_FragColor = vec4(color,1.0);
    }
```

The purpose why I am doing this maybe looks like it's unimportant for many here, but I am really trying to understand how the dot() calculates the correct output in this case in the for loop, knowing the fact that the dot() function itself is correctly reproduced.

I ask for a thorough explanation on this matter with code example if possible.

Comment: The first line `p.x = abs(p.x * 2.003) / (p.x*p.x+p.y*p.y+p.z*p.z) - 0.75;` changes `p.x`. So `p.x` has a different value in the following lines ...

Comment: @Rabbid76 In that case how p = abs(p * 2.003) / dot(p, p) - 0.75; is calculated? I need further explanation please. Is there some parallel calculation going on here, and how to reproduce it?

Comment: @Rabbid76 Thank you, it works now. I have assigned the reproduced dot() into separate variable float pDot = (p.x*p.x+p.y*p.y+p.z*p.z); before the assignment of the values in p.x, p.y and p.z happens accordingly, so pDot will have fixed value until the next loop sequence occurs. Hence, p.x = abs(p.x * 2.003) / pDot - 0.75; and same for the rest two lines.